# What is exactly gravitational potential energy and explain P.E. $= -GMm/r$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, celestial-mechanics

I was studying gravity and I came to know about $P.E.= -\frac{GMm}{r}$ which is derived by $GMm(\frac{1}{\infty} - \frac{1}{r})$  which the work done by the body to displace it from infinity to $r$. But, I thought potential energy is the energy which could be converted to kinetic energy or any other visible form but What I see is ,it  is the work done by gravitational force while displacing some body from infinity to $r$. So, I request true meaning of gravitational potential energy and explaining the formula of $-\frac{GMm}{r}$.